# Adding normal map to custom shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-2dtools, cg

I'm playing with 2D lighting and have things working nicely, except when working with custom materials.  For example, I have a fairly simple shader that gives a sprite an outline glow.  With this material being used by the sprite, however, it can no longer be assigned a normalmap-based material.

Is there a clean way to chain together the normal map functionality that exists in default materials with the custom shader I've written?  Typically, outside shaders, these two functionalities would be seen as components, and there would be no issue with combining them on a single object.

From all my current reading, it seems like the only reasonably efficient way is to extend my custom shader with custom normal map cg code so that all the functionality exists on a single material.  Am I missing a far more obvious approach, or is this really the only practical option?

Comment: Probably.  I can't check though, won't have a computer until next week.

Comment: My current thought is to just duplicate the spriteRenderer so that the same sprite is being rendered via two different materials: a normal map material on the top layer, and the outline glow material beneath it